# How to use AdapterPopulatedRecordArray in Ember Data 1.13

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In older versions of Ember Data, when working with promises inside routes I could write code like:

```
this.store.find('model_name')
.then(function(models) {
    //models would be ready to work with here
}
```

In Ember Data 1.13.15 the promise is fulfilled with an `AdapterPopulatedRecordArray`, which can still be waiting for data from the server. How do I know when the data is available? I see the `AdapterPopulatedRecordArray` has an `isLoaded` property, but watching that property seems like the work the promise used to do?